# What are the settings for log users access to document library (content types added to document library)

Tags: 2013, document-library, auditing

I created a document library and added two content types Hr,Finance that inherit from document content type.

Here I need log for who will (site users ) attempt to access documents from document library either hr documents or finance documents?

How can I configure settings for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as 2013, so I am assuming you are on premises. The default audit log settings, `/_layouts/15/AuditSettings.aspx`, should take care of this for you. It tracks user reads and views if you so choose.

However I wouldn't rely solely on this, ensure the document libraries are secured properly with the desired groups and having only the minimum permissions they need. You can also look at using Information Rights Management on the document libraries to restrict rights and abilities on the documents.

Comment: hi can i use information management policies to content types? and which policy ?

Comment: IRM policies apply to the document library as a whole, if you want different policies based on content type, then they would need to be in separate libraries.